# .closest() does not highlight cell

Tags: jquery, html

The aim is to highlight the cell of selected radio button on page load.

I have the following code:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hryxge5n/1/).

**HTML**

```
<table style='border: 1px solid black;'>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-031e eq q1" >
            <input class="hidden" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c" type="radio" checked="" onclick="mand();">
            c
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($('#q1c').prop('checked')) { 
    alert('checked');
    $(this).closest("td").addClass("selected");
}
```

However, the cell isn't highlighted.

Comment: `this` points to `window` in your code. There is no closest `td` for `window`.

Comment: Thanks Regent, obvious...well it should have been!

Comment: You're welcome. Arun P Johny has provided an example of how it can be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a new block(`{}`) with the `if` statement does not change the context(value referred by `this`), so to refer `#q1c` in the if block you need to use `$('#q1c')`, not `this`(Assuming you want to target the `td` containing `#q1c` element)

```
if ($('#q1c').prop('checked')) {
    alert('checked');
    $('#q1c').closest("td").addClass("selected");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ubv0wf1k/)